# drupal 7 webform: change label of downloaded submissions

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

I have a webform with some form components. I want to download it in CSV. But I would like that the form components labels of the downloaded file to be the machine name (the field key) instead of the label of the form component.

The reason is that I will treat the csv file afterwards and I need those keys, but those are not much human readable. Thats why I have put different more user friendly labels in the webform. But in the downloaded file I got those labels instead of the machine names.

There is an option for the "select" options list, but I have not seen any option for the rest of normal text fields.

I am thinking of some javascript or css to do the dirty trick to put in the label the ugly machine value, but show to the user  the user friendly one. But this would be just a workaround, I guess there is a drupal way to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: to make myself more clear:
When adding a component in the web form there are two mandatory fields: label and " machine name".
I want the label value to be beautiful for the user, and I am using the machine name for my own purposes.
I want that when I download the submited forms in a CSV file, to make the title of each column the "machine name" value instead of the label, which is what I am getting now.

Edit2: well is more elegant to change the labels on the displayed form with a hook form alter instead of js and css! But I still would like to know the answer